# JQuery DataTables prevent actions on the first row

Tags: jquery, datatables

I am using [DataTables](https://www.datatables.net/) plugin for a project of mine. Now what i'm trying to do is quite unique and i'm not too sure how to go about it. Basically in my table of data the very first row will always relate to the logged in user. Therefore whenever sorting, paginating and searching occurs I would like that row to be consistent and never move or disappear. Would be nice if i could apply it to the second row so i could have a kind of like divider row between the personal row and the rest of the data.

How can i approach this?

**EDIT:**

**[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ufehdkww/2/)**, this shows the table now let's presume i'm Mike Man, i would like to be at the top of the table at ALL times. Throughout searches, pagination and sorting.

I have called in the function like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#dataTable").dataTable();
});
```

but i'm expecting i need to tweak it for what i want.

Comment: create a fidle for this

Comment: I have included a fiddle showing what i'm doing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that very easily by dedicating a `<thead>` `<tr>` as always visible "user row". Declare an extra row in `<thead>` :

```
<tr id="userRow">
   <th></th>
   <th></th>
   ...
</tr>
```

Give your originally `<thead>` `<tr>` the id `#sortRow`. In `initComplete` popuplate `#userRow` with the content of the first row, and swap the two `<thead>` `<tr>`'s :

```
initComplete : function() {
   this.api().row(0).data().forEach(function(str, i) {
       $("#userRow th:eq("+i+")").text(str);
   })           
   $("#userRow").before($("#sortRow"));
}
```

demo -> **http://jsfiddle.net/my577xu4/**

In your case you could do the exact same, but your complex of nested tables and really close CSS that styles the content needs som extra hand holded adjustment :

```
initComplete : function() {
   $("#userRow th:eq(0)").html(this.api().row(0).column(0).nodes().to$().html());
   $("#userRow th:eq(1)").html(this.api().row(0).column(1).nodes().to$().html());
   $("#userRow").before($("#sortRow"));
}
```

is almost there, but some CSS makes the purple circle to float around and you need to style the copied nested `<table>` structures as well -> **https://jsfiddle.net/zukbrc57/1/** - I do not dare to try to mess around with such detailed layout :)

Comment: I am right in assuming this will take effect after datatables loads? As i am going to populate using ajax. Taking the html outright will be fine but as long as its done.

Comment: @mdixon18 - unfortunetely there is no `ajaxFinishedPopulateDataDone` callback, but you can use the ajax `dataSrc` callback and a little delay to wait for data to be populated (I have the feeling you have a lot of HTML insertion / manipulation for each cell) and then copy the final rendered HTML content from the first row columns to the "userRow", example -> **http://jsfiddle.net/p37kqonv/**

Answer (score 1):

Store the first row that you want to always be there in a variable, say `var row;`. Assume that your data table has the class `.data-table`, or whatever other selector you wish to use for it. Generate your paginated table as usual without the first row. You can then use the `prepend()` JQuery method on each page in a script to add this row to your table in the following way:

`$('.data-table').prepend(row);`

If you also wish to add a divider after this, just add it at the end of the `row` variable.

Comment: I see, I can store the row globally in var row. But how can I go about tweaking dataTables to prepend it at the correct times?

Comment: If by "correct times", you mean on different pages that you are displaying your data table on, you just have to include the suggested solution in the JavaScript file for that page, or as an inline script in the HTML (the former is preferred for better organization of your code).
If not, please elaborate on what event you wish to prepend the row. You can call this method when the desired event is fired.

Comment: Well what I mean is, surely i need to do the prepend everytime a search is made, pagination is clicked and sort is done. But how do i go about it?

Comment: Just add this code to the end of the (success part of, if applicable) respective methods of the events you mentioned. For example, where your search results would get displayed/paginated results would load, etc. Remember to only do this once for a page of results that gets loaded. Watch out for multiple events that may trigger on a single page load that may redundantly prepend this row. To keep it simple, just add it to the paginated-results-loading method.